# Get Java json in raw format (only enclosing strings with quotes) with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Imagine I have the following JsonObject
`{"name":"Test Name","id":13,"isimportant":true}`

I would like to add this to mysql, so I would iterate through the members with

```
void test(JsonObject jsonobject) {
        String names="";
        String values="";
        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonobject.entrySet();
        for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
            String key=entry.getKey();
            names+="`"+key+"`,";
            values+="\""+jsonobject.get(key).getAsString()+"\",";
        }
        ... create an insert query from the `names` and `values` strings
        ... and add to database
}
```

To make sure the strings are processed correctly, I enclose all the values with quotes, so this would result in a query like

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (name,id,isimportant) VALUES ("Test Name","13","true")
```

I would prefer only to have quotes on the actual string variables, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (name,id,isimportant) VALUES ("Test Name",13,true)
```

using the same formatting as in the original json.

How can this be achieved? I generally use the gson library, i.e. JsonObjects rather than JSONObjects.

Comment: why not parsing them to their respective types ?

Comment: because the actual code contains a lot more variables and it would be a lot easier to just use the formatting from the existing json

Answer (score 0):

Think I found a solution using getAsJsonPrimitive

```
            if (entry.getValue().getAsJsonPrimitive().isString())
                values+="\""+jsonobject.get(key).getAsString()+"\",";
            else
                values+=jsonobject.get(key).getAsString()+",";
```

Since JsonPrimitive still contains the quotes where applicable, one can just do

```
            values+=entry.getValue().getAsJsonPrimitive().toString()+",";
```

which does exactly what I require.